# windows7 laptop computer. cup intelD425-1.80G

Tags: windows-7, windows

It says reboot and select proper  boot device or insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press a key. how should  I do this?

Comment: Is there any USB flash memory or external Hard Disk connected?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your hard drive is dead or you have a device that your system is trying to load first.

A D425 is ~5 years old. Hard drives often last *roughly* that long.

Bad news is if you don't have backups, any data that was on the drive *including* the recovery partition is gone, and well, you may need to reinstall.

Troubleshooting steps, in order would be

1. Disconnect *any* external device. Remove any SD cards, CDs... *ANYTHING* that could be bootable other than any HDD
2. Check if the hard drive is detected in bios.
3. Try reseating the hard drive if it is not
4. Boot from a known good liveusb install of linux (I favour lubuntu or xubuntu) to check if the system is able to boot. If the drive is detected, install gsmartctrl and use that to check if the drive is clearly unhealthy. Run a short smart test from gsmartctrl to make sure there's no errors.
5. If the drive is detected and you want to attempt to do data recovery, try imaging the drive with gddrescue and mount it with kpartx. Dosen't seem likely here.
6. Purchase a new drive, install it, and reinstall your OS.

Answer (score 0):

This message means that the BIOS is not able to locate the boot device on your machine.

It possibly means that the hard drive is dead, or the Windows boot partition on it.

Another possibility is that the boot order setuped in the BIOS configuration does not list the device containting the boot partition.

It can happen if a hard drive is added and if this ones replaces the old one containing Windows in the BIOS boot order list.

- First, check if your hard drive is detected in the BIOS.
- Second, check the boot order device list
- Third, try to boot to a rescue CD
  (LiveCD Linux or else) to check the hard drive sanity.

Answer (score 0):

Like other answers, the hard drive may be dead if you can't boot from it.

What you can try:

- Check to see if there is a clicking sound (Hard Drive is most likely dead then)
- If the Hard Drive is accessible, make sure it is properly connected and screwed in
- Check the BIOS and see if your hard drive is detected in the BIOS Setup. If it is, then you'll need to use a rescue disk to try and recover or get a copy of Windows and reinstall.

You might want to look into getting a SSD if you need a replacement. They are much faster then Hard Drives but don't last as long.

Comment: That they don't last as long is a bit of a myth. They do have different failure modes tho